# Updating entire model object in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an object called `eventData` that is a singleton that is injected into multiple controllers via a resolve.

eventData contains both view data like drop down list values as well as my model.
Basically it looks like this:

```
eventData.DropDownListValues1
eventData.DropDownListValues2
eventData.MyModel
```

Then in each of my controllers I have this:

```
angular.module('myWebApp.controllers').
    controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, eventData, coreAPIservice, ViewMatrixService, UtilityService) {

        $scope.myModel = eventData.MyModel;
        $scope.dropDownListValues1 = eventData.DropDownListValues1;
});
```

And my views look like:

```
<select class="form-control input-sm"
        ng-model="myModel.Item"
        ng-options="myItem as myItem.ItemName for myItem in dropDownList1 track by myItem.ItemId">
    <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Select Item...</option>
</select>
```

After a post my webservice returns the updated model that now contains IDs generated by the database. I tried reassigning over `eventData.MyModel` but it doesn't cause all the controllers referencing `MyModel` to update.

```
coreAPIservice.UpdateEvent(eventData.MyModel).success(function (response) {
    eventData.MyModel = response;
});
```

Normally when I update a property of the model from any controller like this:

`$scope.myModel.myProperty1 = "abcdefg";`

That property change is immediately reflected across all controllers/views that reference `eventData.MyModel`.

My guess is that because I'm replacing the entire `MyModel` object the reference is being lost and therefore the views don't update.

The only options I can think of are re-fetching the data after a post or updating each property individually.

I don't like re-fetching because it's redundant. I already have the updated model from the post. Adding another fetch just slows things down and amounts to a page refresh.

I don't like updating each property individually since there are over 1000 properties on `MyModel` and it would take a while to code and not be very performant.

Comment: How many controllers do you have that need this? You could register a watch (angular event) and fire off an event with the new object when that occurs. The event handlers (method on controllers) would then receive a reference to the new object. If you also have 1000s of controllers this might not work, better to create a more generic means of doing this.

Comment: Can you try using the eventData directly?  $scope.myEventData = eventData; Then use ng-model = myEventData.MyModel.Whatever...

Comment: @Igor I have 7 controllers

Comment: @ZivWeissman Yeah, that could work since you'd still have the reference to eventData. I also found that I can use a broadcast and reassign MyModel in the listener. Do you think your suggestion would run faster?

Comment: I believe it is faster to use my suggestion because you don't reassign and no need for broadcast. You keep the old reference.

Comment: Ok, found a better solution I think. If you do not go for that then I would also recommend you do what @ZivWeissman suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your controller constructor code like this:

```
$scope.eventData= eventData;
Object.defineProperty($scope, "myModel", { get: function () { return $scope.eventData.MyModel; } });
Object.defineProperty($scope, "dropDownListValues1", { get: function () { return $scope.eventData.DropDownListValues1; } });
```

What this does is register myModel as property (not a field) on the $scope. The property then always retrieves the `MyModel` object from the `eventData` when referenced. This will allow you to keep your existing HTML as is. It will also allow you to update the entire model on your `EventData` instance without having to push events through. Your controller will have a reference (as a field) to `EventData` but you do not have to reference that with the exception of in the created getter property.

*You might want to double check my JavaScript syntax, I got it from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)*